# How to modify a segment of Bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash

How to modifiy/manipulate a segment of Bash array as the below fails?

```
$ l=(1 2 3) ; l=([2]=5 6 7)
$ echo ${l[0]};echo ${l[1]};echo ${l[2]};echo ${l[3]};echo ${l[4]};echo ${l[5]}


5
6
7
```

instead of

```
1
2
5
6
7
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `+=` operator instead.

```
$ l=(1 2 3)
$ l+=([2]=5 6 7)
$ declare -p l
declare -a l=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="5" [3]="6" [4]="7")
```

Comment: I agree it's a bug (or at best a misfeature), which I'm sure is why it got changed. But I can't count on my scripts running under bash 5 (especially since I mostly deal with macOS, which ships with bash 3.2.57 and always will).